# why the array print at the end different elements?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int *position(int N,int vet2[], int x, int pos){
    N++;
    for(int i = N;i>=pos;i--){
        vet2[i]=vet2[i-1];
    }
    vet2[pos-1]= x;
    return vet2;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int N;
    cout<<"insert the dimention of the array"<<endl;
    do{
        cin>>N;
    }while((N%2)!=0);
    int vet[N],vet2[N];
    cout<<"insert the elements of the array"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
        cin>>vet[i];
    }
    cout<<"the elements of the array n°1 are:"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
        cout<<vet[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
        vet2[i]=vet[i];
    }
    int x = 0;
    int pos = 2;
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
        position(N, vet2, x, pos);
        pos += 2;
    }
    cout<<"the elements of array n°2 are:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0;i<2*N;i++){
        cout<<vet2[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example: input of the array is `1 2 3 4 5 6` and the output of vet2 must be `1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0` but  when the program compiled the output of vet2 is `1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 1 0 3 0`

Why this happens, I really don't know why the array prints different elements?

Comment: Hint: which elements of `vet2` does `position` access?  But how many elements does it actually have?

Comment: Consider using a debugger and stepping through the program.

Comment: @NateEldredge the vector must have the 2*N elements

Comment: @Jack_01 `int vet[N],vet2[N];` -- Let's start by stating that this is not valid C++.  C++ requires arrays to have sizes denoted by compile-time expression, not runtime values.  A dynamic array in C++ is `std::vector`, thus `std::vector<int> vet(N), vet2(N);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make an array `vet2` of size `N`

```
int vet[N],vet2[N];
```

but then your program assumes that it has a size of `2*N`.

```
for (int i = 0;i<2*N;i++){
    cout<<vet2[i]<<" ";
```

Change

```
int vet[N],vet2[N];
```

to

```
int vet[N],vet2[2*N];
```

***EDIT***

The `position` function is bugged. There's no need for it, change this code

```
for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
    vet2[i]=vet[i];
}
int x = 0;
int pos = 2;
for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
    position(N, vet2, x, pos);
    pos += 2;
}
```

to the much simpler

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    vet2[2*i] = vec[i];
    vet2[2*i + 1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to run the program with this change but the output of vet2 is  `1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 6 0 12080 0`

Comment: @Jack_01 Looks like you also have a bug in your position function. It seems excessively complex to me. You only need one loop to make the change you want, but you have two loops for some reason.

Comment: @Jack_01 See the latest edit for some (hopefully) working code.